# Android Studio saving data in database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm new here, and also new to Android Studio. 
My first project is to create a diary to save a users workouts. 
I'm having trouble saving for this data..

Here is my [front page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuKOc.png) for the app. With the button "[Styrkeboken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYxPe.png)" (Strengthbook) I'll be entering my sets, reps, weight(vikt) and excercise(övning). I want to save this data in the second button "Historik" (History), but I can't manage it to work as I want to..

Code from my class "Pass" (Workout):

```
package com.example.mama0086.styrkeboken;
```

public class Pass {

```
private int _set;
private int _reps;
private float _vikt;
private String _övning;

public Pass() {
}

public Pass(int set, int reps, float vikt, String övning) {
    this._set = set;
    this._reps = reps;
    this._vikt = vikt;                  //Vikt = weight
    this._övning = övning;              //Övning = excercise
}
public void set_set(int _set) {

    this._set = _set;
}
public void set_reps(int _reps) {

    this._reps = _reps;
}
public void set_vikt(float _vikt) {

    this._vikt = _vikt;
}
public void set_övning(String _övning) {

    this._övning = _övning;
}
public int get_set() {

    return _set;
}
public int get_reps() {

    return _reps;
}
public float get_vikt() {

    return _vikt;
}
public String get_övning() {

    return _övning;
}
```

}

Code from my class "Historik" (History):

public class Historik extends AppCompatActivity {

```
EditText editSet;
TextView textSet;
EditText editReps;
TextView textReps;
EditText editVikt;
TextView textVikt;
EditText editÖvning;
TextView textÖvning;
MyDBHandler dbHandler;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_historik);
    editSet = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editSet);
    textSet = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textSet);
    editReps = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editReps);
    textReps = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textReps);
    editVikt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editVikt);
    textVikt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textVikt);
    editÖvning = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editÖvning);
    textÖvning = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textÖvning);
    dbHandler = new MyDBHandler(this, null, null, 1);
    printDatabase();

}

//Add excercise
public void addBtn(View view){
    Pass pass = new Pass(textSet.getText().toString());     //Pass is swedish for work-out
    dbHandler.addPass(pass);
    printDatabase();
}
public void removeBtn(){
    String inputText = textSet.getText().toString();
    dbHandler.deletePass(inputText);
    printDatabase();
}

public void printDatabase(){
    String dbString = dbHandler.historikToString();
    textSet.setText(dbString);
    editSet.setText("");
    textReps.setText(dbString);
    editReps.setText("");
    textVikt.setText(dbString);
    editVikt.setText("");
    textÖvning.setText(dbString);
    editÖvning.setText("");
}
```

}

In the "Historik" class I get this error message:
"Cannot resolve constructor 'Pass(java.lang.String)'

please let me know if you need the code for my database.
I appreciate the help!

Comment: post your dbhelper class... and what you mean by **I can't manage it to work as I want to..** ??

Answer (score 1):

You defined 2 different constructors for your `Pass` class :

```
public Pass() {
```

}

```
public Pass(int set, int reps, float vikt, String övning) {
    this._set = set;
    this._reps = reps;
    this._vikt = vikt;                  //Vikt = weight
    this._övning = övning;              //Övning = excercise
}
```

However in your `Historik` activity, you're trying to instantiate a new `Pass` with a String only as a parameter `Pass pass = new Pass(textSet.getText().toString());`

You will need to change this line to match one of the 2 constructors you have, or define a 3rd one taking only a String as argument

EDIT : Depending on your `Pass` object, you can either :

1. declare a 3rd constructor taking only a String (I assume it's övning)

   public Pass(String övning) {
     this._övning = övning;
   }
2. if the `textSet.getText().toString()` is not relevant, simply use the default constructor `Pass pass = new Pass();`

Comment: It doesn't work.. And I dont know why..

EDIT:
This is my code for the button "Styrkeboken"
Do I need to change or do something here to be able to save the data in the other button "Historik" ?

public class Styrkeboken extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_styrkeboken);


    }
}

Comment: Are you getting another error then? Because the error you linked `Cannot resolve constructor 'Pass(java.lang.String)` should be fixed with what I provided to you

Comment: The error "Cannot resolve constructor 'Pass(java.lang.String)" Disappear, but when I enter data into the four given fields (Set, Reps, Vikt, Övning) And then press "Lägg till" (Add), a box pops up saying "Unfortunately Styrkeboken has stopped".

Comment: Then the issue is either in the `dbHandler.addPass(pass)` or the `printDatabase()`. What does the logcat tell you? what's the error you're getting?